# I connect to phpmyadmin but this is the result

Tags: phpmyadmin

My server is functional (active), the port is well configured, also, I edited the file /ect/apache2/apache.conf/ followed by a /etc/init.d/apache2 restart and it gives me this:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I can't see a problem in your screenshot.

Comment: Ah, you mean that PHP is not rendering your content, and you are seeing your PHP as plain text. Try installing `mod_php` via Apt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.